# How to include records from 2 db tables into a single view using NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm new to NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate (started with it this weekend) and I'm having difficulties solving the following.

I have 2 SQL Server tables:

```
[Client]

ID        INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
Name      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
Email     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
BirthDate DATE

[Phones]

ID       INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
Number   VARCHAR(14)
Category INT
ClientID INT         NOT NULL     
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Client](ID),
```

POCO classes:

```
public class Clients
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Phones Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phones
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneCategory.PCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Clients Client { get; set; }
}

public static class PhoneCategory
{
    public enum PCategory
    {
        Personal,
        Comercial,
        Residential,
        Other
    }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ClientsMap : ClassMap<Clients>
{
    public ClientsMap()
    {
        Table("Clients");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.BirthDate);
        References(x => x.Phones).Column("ClientID").Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class PhonesMap : ClassMap<Phones>
{
    public PhonesMap()
    {
        Table("Phones");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Number);
        Map(x => x.Category).CustomType<PhoneCategory.PCategory>();
    }
}
```

My view for the Clients class is working fine, I can save, update, list and delete. But how could I include the records of the Phones class?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `References(x => x.Phones).Column("ClientID").Cascade.All();` line in the `ClientsMap`, you need to use the `HasMany()` method.

E.g.

```
HasMany(c => c.Phones)
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#hasmany--one-to-many).